# identifier "cout" is undefined while already include iostream and use namespace std

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code

I was setting up VS Code to program in c++, but quickly confronted the problem: `identifier "cout" is undefined`.

```cpp
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    cout << 1; // identifier "cout" is undefined C/C++(20)
    return 0;
}
```

But I ctrl + click `cout`, it successfully goto `iostream` library.

When modified as follows, it got `namespace "std" has no member "cout"`:

```cpp
#include<iostream>

int main() {
    std::cout << 1; // namespace "std" has no member "cout" C/C++(135)
    return 0;
}
```

By the way, the problem occurred after I reinstalled the system. There wasn't such problem before. All the settings are synchronized via my account.

Additional screenshots:

[when ctrl+click `cout`](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lZFcl.png)

[`C_Cpp.default.includePath`](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bGvc1.png)

Comment: Is it problem with Intellisense or compiler?

Comment: Show your .json configuration files.

Comment: Why do you have both tdmgcc and mingw64 in include paths? That's looking for trouble.

Comment: On a side note, I recommend following: Uninstall your compiler(s), uninstall/disable the stock microsoft intellisense, use [MSYS2](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30069830/2752075) to install both GCC and Clangd, install the Clangd plugin in VSCode (and configure it to use the Clangd installed from MSYS2). You'll then have a sane code completion that works out of the box with no configuration.

Comment: Oh, one more thing, it still can compile: `cd "d:\Desktop\" ; if ($?) { g++ -std=c++11 1.cpp -o 1 } ; if ($?) { .\1 }` 
which output 1.

Comment: Using `#` instead of `//` to make comments in code is not going to work unless your compiler has a very unusual extension.

Comment: VSCode isn't beginner-friendly. I recommend a C++ IDE, e.g. Visual Studio, CLion, Eclipse CDT. There are so many questions about VSCode because the configuration is too complex for beginners.

Answer (score 0):

Might be an issue with intellisense and VSCode. Try searching VSCode extensions for C++ code support and intellisense and then reboot.